# How to hide whizzytex yellow cursor in Emacs

Tags: emacs, tex

How to hide it? It is way too yellow, and automatically switched on when activating whizzytex.
I looked at the Emacs variables but cannot find it there.
Using Ubuntu 13.04 and Emacs 24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for customize-group (`M-x customize-group RET`). The group will be called WhizzyTeX. There you will find "Whizzy Point Face". Untick the background-color box, set for current session and save for future sessions.